# Missing WindowedApplication chrome on Flex4 + AIR 2.0beta2

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, air2

I've installed the Flex 4 SDK and overlayed it with the AIR 2.0beta2 SDK and am unable to bet the Flex chrome to show up when I try to use Spark's WindowedApplication.

the simple MXML -> http://pastie.org/909375

When I use the MX WindowApplication everything works fine, but somehow I'm not getting the Spark version to work as I expect.

What am I doing wrong?

Jon

Comment: the app descriptor i'm using is http://pastie.org/909380

Answer (score 0):

```
WindowedApplication {
   skinClass:ClassReference("spark.skins.spark.SparkChromeWindowedApplicationSkin");  
}
```